# What does $@ mean as a bash script function parameter

Tags: bash, shell

What does `$@` mean as a bash script function parameter?

Example:

```
function foo()
{
    echo "$@" 1>&2;
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `$@` variable expands to all the parameters used when calling the function, so

```
function foo()
{
    echo "$@"
}

foo 1 2 3
```

would display `1 2 3`. If not used inside a function, it specifies all parameters used when calling the script. See the [bash manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) for more info.

Answer (score 17):

$@ is one of the two "positional parameter" representions in bash, the other being $*.

Both, $@ and $* are internal bash variables that represents all parameters passed into a function or a script, with **one key difference**, $@ has each parameter as a separate quoted string, whereas $* has all parameters as a **single** string. That difference is shown in the following code:

```
foo() {
  while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
      echo $1
    shift
  done
}

dollar_at () {
    foo "$@"
}

dollar_star () {
    foo "$*"
}

echo "Using \$@"
dollar_at a b c

echo "Using \$*"
dollar_star a b c
```

Output:

```
Using $@
a
b
c
Using $*
a b c
```

Note, when called with $*, exactly one argument is passed to foo(), but with $@ three arguments are passed to foo().

More info: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF

Answer (score 0):

I expect it means take as a hash all input parameters. So if there are 3 input parameters they will be available within the function  in the form  of $1, $2, $3

Comment: No, it is an internal variable meaning all parameters given to a function. They are available as `$1`,`$2` etc anyway, irrespective of `$@`.